# What is the difference between yay -Sc and yay -Scc?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, aur, disk-cleanup

I have seen seen people online use
`yay -Sc`,
but I have also seen people use
`yay -Scc`

What is the difference? There is a man page segment for `yay -Sc`:

```
   -Sc    Yay  will also clean cached AUR package and any untracked Files in the
          cache. Cleaning untracked files will wipe any  downloaded  sources  or
          built packages but will keep already downloaded vcs sources.
```

But nothing for `yay -Scc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `yay` tries to mimic `pacman`'s switches, check [`pacman`'s documentation](https://man.archlinux.org/man/pacman.8#SYNC_OPTIONS_(APPLY_TO_-S)) (emphasis added):

```
-c, --clean
   Remove packages that are no longer installed from the cache as well
   as currently unused sync databases to free up disk space. When
   pacman downloads packages, it saves them in a cache directory. In
   addition, databases are saved for every sync DB you download from
   and are not deleted even if they are removed from the configuration
   file pacman.conf(5). Use one --clean switch to only remove packages
   that are no longer installed; use two to remove all files from the
   cache. In both cases, you will have a yes or no option to remove
   packages and/or unused downloaded databases.
```